# Background Image won't stretch all the way in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, background-image, css

I have an image that I am using as my background and am trying to have it fill the width of the screen 100%.  I have applied background-size:100% and in MZF it works, but in IE it won't stretch anymore.  Does anyone know a work around for this?

Here is the HTML...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        </head>
<body class="body">
            <!--Container to hold everything in the middle of page-->
            <div class="container">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the CSS..

```
.body
{
    background-image: url(final2.gif);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color:#C2C2C2;
}

.container {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1930px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: I like this part `body class="body"` :D

Comment: what version(s) of IE are you testing with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/j5q63/

You can emulate a background using an image just after `<body>`:

```
<img id="bg" src="path/to/your/image.png" />
```

And then

```
#bg{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;left:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Comment: @FirstLast Yes, or at some place where it hasn't any parents with `position` different than `static`.

Answer (score 1):

You might also try to use IE-specific alphaImageLoader. Just add

```
.body {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='final2.gif', sizingMethod='scale');
}
```

to your stylesheet. Or, preferably, create a new IE7/IE8 specific css (included via [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)) and put this style in it.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what versions of IE you're testing against. This is important, because the various versions of IE have very different capabilities and quirks.

In this case, I am guessing that you're using IE8, because in IE8 and earlier the CSS `background-size` feature is not supported.

There are a number of solutions. Sadly none of them are great, but I'd suggest using a javascript polyfill solution that allows you to keep the existing CSS code for other browsers. The next best solution is to replace the background image with an `<img>` tag layered behind the existing element. A javascript polyfill will probably do this same technique, but transparently to you, so you can keep using the existing CSS.

Some scripts you could use:

- http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/
- https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.backgroundSize.js
  (both of these are jquery plugins, but you should be able to find ones that don't require jquery if you're not using it)

Hope that helps.